# В каких случаях Quartz создает триггер, название которого начинается с "MT_"

Tags: c#, .net, quartz

Вводные:

1. Используем Quartz.NET
2. У меня есть работа, которая должна выполняться каждую минуту. Т.е.
   триггер будет срабатывать каждую минуту, вызывать соответствующую
   работу и что-то делать. Бывают случаи, когда за отведенную минуту
   работа все свои действия выполнить не успевает. В этом случае два
   вызова одного триггера как бы накладываются друг на друга. Чтобы
   работы не выполнялись параллельно, на ней установлен атрибут
   DisallowConcurrentExecution (запрещает параллельное выполнение).

Поведение:

1. В начале минуты просыпается триггер и вызывает конкретную работу.
2. В работе проводятся подготовительные действия и далее вызываем из
   нее операцию в WCF-сервисе.
3. Эта операция может выполняться дольше минуты. Работа все это время
   ждет, когда сервис выполнится.
4. После того, как сервис выполнился, продолжается выполнение
   оставшейся части работы.

Проблема:
Опытным путем мы заметили, что после того, как произошел вызов сервиса, тут же уже самим кварцем создается дополнительный триггер, TriggerKey которого начинается с "MT_". Что это такое? Почему сам по себе создался новый триггер? В каких случаях создаются триггеры "MT_"? Почему такие триггеры сами по себе потом удаляются? Хочется понять природу его появления. Может мы что-то не так у себя делаем.

Comment: Вы используете только `Quartz.NET` или в связке с чем то вроде `Topshelf`?

Comment: Да, конечно с Topshelf. С его помощью quartz в виде службы развернут.

Comment: Да и вообще какая-то мутная тема с этими "MT_" триггерами. На оф.сайте quartz пишут, что это триггеры, запущенные вручную (manual trigger = mt), но что именно под этим понимается не приводится. Притом такие триггеры всегда являются SimpleTrigger. Откуда они берутся большая загадка. Ни наше приложение, ни уж тем более пользователь, триггер руками не создает.

Comment: Наверное имеется в виду что manual будет запущен планировщиков "в ручную" сразу же после окончания передувающей джобы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С проблемой разобрался самостоятельно. Оставляю ответ для тех, кто возможно также столкнется с описанной в вопросе проблемой.

Триггеры, TriggerName которых наименование с "MT_", порождаются следующим методом Quartz'a:

```
void TriggerJob(JobKey jobKey);
void TriggerJob(JobKey jobKey, JobDataMap data);
```

Эти методы предназначены для того, чтобы моментально запустить некую работу на выполнение, а не по наступлению определенного времени. Но запускают они работу исключительно в виде SimpleTrigger. Собственно для SimpleTrigger и предназначен этот метод. А для CronTrigger'ов в Quartz отсутствует возможность моментального запуска, т.к. минимальное время, которое можно задать CRON-выражением - минута.